# How great custom post type can be?

Tags: custom-post-types

You know how sweet it is WP with its plugins and custom post types. I love WP so much until i have come to a thought that most of any kind of website can be done in WP.

Recently my boss want me to build a hotel/accomodation searching website. Its like hotels.com kind of website except there is no booking feature.

My question is, can i do this in WP if i use its custom post types ability or worst is create a dedicated plugin for it? what do you think of this as WP expert?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with custom post types, but there are already quite a few plugins out there that do this. You might want to try [StayPress](http://staypress.com/).

Best of luck!